# What is considered the higher punishment by the Imperium: Penal Legion or Servitor?

Tags: warhammer-40k, crime

There are two famous ways to punish criminals in the Imperium: make them a servitor or consign them into a penal legion. I am aware that the people punished in either way are different. Most criminals used as servitors are criminals against the Adeptus Mechanicus whereas penal legions consists (mostly) of ex-members of the Imperial Army / Navy that turned criminals.

Nonetheless, is there one of the two punishments that is considered a greater punishment than the other?

Just to clarify and not get the question closed as 'opinion based': I know what a servitor is, that they are mind-wiped (although imperfect) and am not interested in a "description" of what consists of each punishment and a conclusion that A is therefore worse than B. I'd like a reference from an *official source* where e.g. a Judge mentions something like "That crime is not severe enough for Servitor, he's going to serve in a penal legion" or something like that.

Comment: Lexicanum describe Penal Legions as "Imperial Guard forces consisting entirely of convicted criminals, debtors, liberals and other social transgressors" (but the source is Rogue Trader, so it very old fluff). So it does not seem that what the judges have in mind the appropriateness of the punishment but how to purge the society and get inexpensive cannon fodder.

Comment: It's not clear whether there ever is an option for the Mechanicus to send people to a penal legion, nor the navy to be servitors, so I don't think you'll get an answer. Though servitor is clearly worse.